# Why postgresql use 100% cpu when i put in ANY more then ~15000 parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

This is my query: `select * from dbname where user_name = any(cast(? as text[]))`

My conf file:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 3GB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 300MB
min_wal_size = 512MB
max_wal_size = 2GB
```

When i put less then ~15000 all works fine.

Postgresq 9.5.

Comment: _Why_ are you putting 15K parameters into an `ANY` clause?  Shouldn't those values be in a table somewhere?  My vote is to fix your data model/query.

Comment: I need to know what objects are already contained in the database and what else i need to add in one query is more faster then i check every object. Maybe you could advise how to do it better and faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name great solution, it was faster and supports more than 15,000. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is possible with Hibernate, but you could try a join instead:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t 
   join unnest(cast(? as text[])) as x(name) on t.user_name = x.name
```